# Is using /AE compulsory?

Tags: united-states, legal, license, callsign

I'm taking the exam to upgrade my licence to Extra soon, but I'm concerned the ULS might not update in time for Field Day, when I'm supposed to be supervising (and using my call-sign for) my club's GOTA station.

If I'm not operating outside the portion of the spectrum permitted to General class licencees, do I need to use the /AE suffix?

My reading of §97.119.f.3 Seems to indicate that I MUST use the suffix if I pass, even when in the general portion of the band.

Comment: When I passed the AE exam at an AARL VEC, the database updated within 5 days.

Comment: I had this same question when I first upgraded. I ended up using it the whole time until my new call sign came

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key wording is in 97.9(b) as referenced in 97.119:

> ...is authorized to exercise the rights and privileges of the higher operator class...

and 97.119 says:

> "When the control operator is a person who is exercising the rights and privileges authorized by §97.9(b)..."

So you only need to use the /AE suffix when you are using privileges only available to an extra class operator.

Best of luck on the exam!